range($g\circ f$)= range($g$) iff Nul($g$)+range($f$)= $F$
Let $E,F,G$ be vector spaces, and $f\in L(E,F)$ and $g\in L(F,G)$.
Prove or disprove:
range($g\circ f$)= range($g$) if and only if Nul($g$)+range($f$)= $F$
I don't know this statement is true or not. I first start with:
Suppose range($g\circ f$) = range($g$), then range($g$) = { $g(v_1)$ : $v_1\in F$ } = { $g(f(v_2))$ : $v_2\in E$ } = range($g\circ f$). Since $f(v_2)$ is the range($f$), then range($f$) = $F$. But I can't prove that Nul($g$) = { $0$ }.
And I have zero idea with another side. Please give some hints.

First let us prove "$Im( g\circ f)=Im(g) \implies ker(g)+Im(f)=F$".
Let $y\in F$ be arbitrary, then by assumption we have $g(y)=g(f(x))$ for some $x\in E$. Rewriting, we have $g(y)-g(f(x))=0=g(y-f(x))$ by linearity.
Thus $y-f(x)=k\in ker(g)$ and $y=k+f(x)\in ker(g)+Im(f)$ as required.

Now proving "$ker(g)+Im(f)=F \implies Im( g\circ f)=Im(g)$".
Let $y\in Im(g)$. Then $y=g(x)$ for some $x\in F.$
By our assumption, since $x\in F$, we can write it as $x=k+i$ for some $k\in ker(g)$ and $i\in Im(f)$. Write $i=f(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in E$.
Then $y=g(x)=g(k+i)=g(i)=g(f(\alpha)) \in  Im(g\circ f)$.
We have shown $Im(g)\subseteq Im(g\circ f)$. The reverse inclusion is obvious.

Write $i = f(\alpha) $ for some $\alpha \in F$. Should it be $\alpha \in E$?

@Felix Yes, corrected.
